# addEventListener и bind

Tags: javascript

В коде ниже присутствуют 2 метода. _open и _close, которые изменяют видимость элемента (ul списка). _open генерируется при клике на кнопку, делает видимым список и навешивает новый обработчик на onclick. В дальнейшем, при клике на любой области кроме кнопки и списка, список должен свернуться обратно. Но каким образом возможно удалить ранее навешанный обработчик? Понимаю, что его нужно как - то занести в отдельную переменную, но в реалиях прототипа у меня картины особо не выстраивается итоговой.

```js
class CustomSelect{
  constructor(options){
    this._elem = options.elem;
    this._elem.onclick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }

  _onClick(event){
    let target = event.target;
    if (target.closest('.title')) this._open();
    else this._close();
  }

  _open(){
    this._elem.classList.add('open');
    document.addEventListener('click', this._onClickOutside.bind(this));
  }

  _close(){
    this._elem.classList.remove('open');
    document.removeEventListener('click', this._onClickOutside.bind(this));
  }

  _onClickOutside(e){
    if (!this._elem.contains(e.target))
    this._close();
  }

}

var animalSelect = new CustomSelect({
  elem: document.getElementById('animal-select')
});
```

```css
.customselect {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customselect .title {
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px groove #ADD8E6;
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.customselect li {
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.customselect li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f0f8ff;
}

.customselect li:hover {
  background-color: #7fffd4;
}

.customselect ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #add8e6;
  border-left: 1px solid #add8e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #add8e6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.customselect.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="animal-select" class="customselect">
    <button class="title">Выберите</button>
    <ul>
      <!-- значение хранится в свойстве data-value -->
      <li data-value="bird">Птицы</li>
      <li data-value="fish">Рыбы</li>
      <li data-value="animal">Звери</li>
      <li data-value="dino">Динозавры</li>
      <li data-value="simplest">Одноклеточные</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: `this._onClickOutside.bind(this)` каждый раз создает новую функцию. Вы можете ее сохранить, а потом использовать в `removeEventListener`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, мне просто необходимо дабы в методе _onClickOutside, this ссылался не на объект, на котором был пойман клик, а на CustomEvent (класс) и именно здесь у меня непонятности возникают. Если биндить в отдельную переменную - для обращения к этой переменной так или иначе нужно использовать this, соответственно опять необходимо как-то изменять this, получаемый при событии клика и в тут у меня замкнутый круг какой-то в голове случается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе просто создайте св-во, которое будет хранить забиндженную функцию

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.methodBound = this.method.bind(this);

    body.addEventListener('click', this.methodBound);
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this);
    body.removeListener('click', this.methodBound);
  }
}
```